PyMongo on Azure Cosmos and MongoDB
I created an Azure Cosmos (RU) Serverless database (sharded) with a MongoDB engine and would like to use Python and pymongo to run queries on it. I am not managing to connect to it in any way.
I have tested both version 3.6 and version 7.0 of the Mongo DB Server.

The connection string I use has this format:
mongodb://{user_name}:{primary_key}@{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@{service_name}@

I tried different versions of pymongo, but no luck. Tested on different networks (no firewall connectivity problems).
Also, with azure-cosmos the connection works, but it cannot be used for nosql engines.
The code I use is as follows. It goes into a timeout:
import pymongo

CONN_STRING = “mongodb://etc....”

client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONN_STRING)

client.list_database_names()

Error:
{
    "name": "ServerSelectionTimeoutError",
    "message": "{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6734b32d878003e1a30f46fb, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: timed out')>]>",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServerSelectionTimeoutError               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 client.list_database_names()

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py:1918, in MongoClient.list_database_names(self, session)
   1908 def list_database_names(self, session=None):
   1909     \"\"\"Get a list of the names of all databases on the connected server.
   1910 
   1911     :Parameters:
   (...)
   1915     .. versionadded:: 3.6
   1916     \"\"\"
   1917     return [doc[\"name\"]
-> 1918             for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py:1899, in MongoClient.list_databases(self, session, **kwargs)
   1897 cmd.update(kwargs)
   1898 admin = self._database_default_options(\"admin\")
-> 1899 res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
   1900 # listDatabases doesn't return a cursor (yet). Fake one.
   1901 cursor = {
   1902     \"id\": 0,
   1903     \"firstBatch\": res[\"databases\"],
   1904     \"ns\": \"admin.$cmd\",
   1905 }

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\database.py:755, in Database._retryable_read_command(self, command, value, check, allowable_errors, read_preference, codec_options, session, **kwargs)
    750 def _cmd(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok):
    751     return self._command(sock_info, command, slave_ok, value,
    752                          check, allowable_errors, read_preference,
    753                          codec_options, session=session, **kwargs)
--> 755 return self.__client._retryable_read(
    756     _cmd, read_preference, session)

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py:1460, in MongoClient._retryable_read(self, func, read_pref, session, address, retryable, exhaust)
   1458 while True:
   1459     try:
-> 1460         server = self._select_server(
   1461             read_pref, session, address=address)
   1462         if not server.description.retryable_reads_supported:
   1463             retryable = False

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py:1278, in MongoClient._select_server(self, server_selector, session, address)
   1275         raise AutoReconnect('server %s:%d no longer available'
   1276                             % address)
   1277 else:
-> 1278     server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
   1279     # Pin this session to the selected server if it's performing a
   1280     # sharded transaction.
   1281     if server.description.mongos and (session and
   1282                                       session.in_transaction):

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py:241, in Topology.select_server(self, selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
    236 def select_server(self,
    237                   selector,
    238                   server_selection_timeout=None,
    239                   address=None):
    240     \"\"\"Like select_servers, but choose a random server if several match.\"\"\"
--> 241     return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
    242                                              server_selection_timeout,
    243                                              address))

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py:199, in Topology.select_servers(self, selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
    196     server_timeout = server_selection_timeout
    198 with self._lock:
--> 199     server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
    200         selector, server_timeout, address)
    202     return [self.get_server_by_address(sd.address)
    203             for sd in server_descriptions]

File ...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py:215, in Topology._select_servers_loop(self, selector, timeout, address)
    212 while not server_descriptions:
    213     # No suitable servers.
    214     if timeout == 0 or now > end_time:
--> 215         raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
    216             \"%s, Timeout: %ss, Topology Description: %r\" %
    217             (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description))
    219     self._ensure_opened()
    220     self._request_check_all()

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: {service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6734b32d878003e1a30f46fb, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: timed out')>]>"
}```


Did you redact the service name from the error message, or is it actually trying to connect to a host named {service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com?


ServerSelectionTimeoutError

The above error may occur because of using MongoClient without importing it from pymongo. Try with the below code, it imports MongoClient  from pymongo.
from pymongo import MongoClient

username = "<user_name>"
primary_key = "<primary_password>"
service_name = "<service_name>"

connection_string = (
    f"mongodb://{username}:{primary_key}@{service_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/"
    "?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@{service_name}@"
)

try:
    client = MongoClient(connection_string, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=60000)

    db_names = client.list_database_names()
    print("Connected successfully. Databases:")
    print(db_names)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Connection failed: {e}")

Output:
Connected successfully. Databases:
['newdb']


Here is an easy way, Goto your Azure Cosmos DB Mongo RU account and navigate to quick start, you will find Python sample in the quick start, just download and repalce the variable names in the code, you will be good to go,
Here is the client code,
  """Connect to the API for MongoDB, create DB and collection, perform CRUD operations"""
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)
    try:
        client.server_info() # validate connection string
    except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError("Invalid API for MongoDB connection string or timed out when attempting to connect")

